# perform lookup on two lists and add element from second list to first list based on condition

Tags: python, list

I have two lists that I have looped over to match an element from the 1st list `vals1` in the second one `vals2`. If the element indexed[0] from `vals1` is present in `vals2` index[0], I need to grad the element index[1] from `vals2` and replace the element indexed[0] from `vals1`. If it isn't present, I want to keep the existing element from `vals1` as is.

So if `vals1` = `[[callid1, 2021/06/04, 1000, 9000], [callid2, 2021/06/04, 1001, 9001], [callid3, 2021/06/04, 1000, 9000], [callid4, 2021/06/04, 1002, 9002]]`

and `vals1` = `[[Tom, 'some value', 1000], [Sara, 'some value', 1001], [Pat, 'some value', 1003], [Craig, 'some value', 1004]]`

The output I'm looking to achieve on `vals1` is:

`[[callid1, 2021/06/04, Tom, 9000], [callid2, 2021/06/04, Sara, 9001], [callid3, 2021/06/04, Tom, 9000], [callid4, 2021/06/04, 1002, 9002]]`

I have only recently started learning Python but could achieve this in Apps Script using a ForEach loop and calling .find() for each iteration.

I have tried the below, which gives the desired output, but returns its twice.

```
def lookups(vals1, vals2):

    for x in vals1:
        for y in vals2:
            if x[3] == y[3]:
                x[3] = y[0]
    
    return calls
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but based on your examples I would say that with your function only the indices would have to be changed.

```py
def lookups(vals1, vals2):
    for x in vals1:
        for y in vals2:
            if x[2] == y[2]:
                x[2] = y[0]
                
vals1 = [['callid1', '2021/06/04', 1000, 9000], ['callid2', '2021/06/04', 1001, 9001], ['callid3', '2021/06/04', 1000, 9000], ['callid4', '2021/06/04', 1002, 9002]]
vals2 = [['Tom', 'some value', 1000], ['Sara', 'some value', 1001], ['Pat', 'some value', 1003], ['Craig', 'some value', 1004]]
                
lookups(vals1, vals2)
            
print(vals1)
```

This code snippet prints the desired output:

```
[['callid1', '2021/06/04', 'Tom', 9000], ['callid2', '2021/06/04', 'Sara', 9001], ['callid3', '2021/06/04', 'Tom', 9000], ['callid4', '2021/06/04', 1002, 9002]]
```

Comment: Oh damn. Correct @Remco646. I adapted my example from my original script and got the index's wrong. The is an elif statement in my original script which replaces a second value. After going through the entire script, the issue was that I had the incorrect mode when writing to the excel sheet. Sorry about that. I'll get better at this. Thanks for your response, much appreciated.